# Snake in Javascript

Tags: javascript, snake-game

I feel like there's something wrong with the way my code is styled but I can't quite place what's wrong with it. Perhaps the way I've represented the snake is a little convoluted?

````
const HEIGHT = 20;
const WIDTH = 20;

const snake = function() {
    const snakeCoordinates = [[0, 0], [1, 0]];
    const moveDirections = [[-1, 0], [-1, 0]];

    function shiftDirections() {
        for (let i = snakeCoordinates.length; i > 0; i--) 
            moveDirections[i] = moveDirections[i - 1];
    }

    return {
        hasSnake: function(row, col) {
            return snakeCoordinates.reduce((accum, [snakeRow, snakeCol]) => accum || (row === snakeRow && col === snakeCol), false);
        },

        expandSnake: function() {       
            const head = snakeCoordinates[0];
            const headDirection = moveDirections[0];

            snakeCoordinates.unshift(wrapAround([head[0] + headDirection[0], head[1] + headDirection[1]])); 
            moveDirections.unshift(headDirection);
        },

        changeDirection: function(x, y) {
            const isAboutTurn = x === -moveDirections[0][0] || y === -moveDirections[0][1];

            if (!isAboutTurn)
                moveDirections[0] = [x, y];
        },

        getSnakeHead: function() {
            return snakeCoordinates[0];
        },

        isSnakeDead: function() {
            const tail = snakeCoordinates.slice(1);
            const head = snakeCoordinates[0];

            return tail.reduce((accum, [row, col]) => accum || (row === head[0] && col === head[1]), false);
        },

        moveSnake: function() {         
            for (let i = 0; i < snakeCoordinates.length; i++) {
                snakeCoordinates[i][0] += moveDirections[i][0];
                snakeCoordinates[i][1] += moveDirections[i][1];

                snakeCoordinates[i] = wrapAround(snakeCoordinates[i]);
            }                   

            shiftDirections();  
        }
    };
}();

const goal = function() {
    var goal = [HEIGHT - 1, WIDTH - 1];

    return {
        newGoal: function() {
            goal = [rng(0, HEIGHT), rng(0, WIDTH)];
        },

        isGoal: function(row, col) {
            return goal[0] === row && goal[1] === col;
        }
    };
}();

initialiseGame();

function initialiseGame() {
    initialiseGridInDOM();
    addEventListeners();

    runGame();
}

function addEventListeners() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", dealWithKeyPress);
}

// Map key press onto action
function dealWithKeyPress(keyPress) {
    const leftArrow = 37;
    const upArrow = 38;
    const rightArrow = 39;
    const downArrow = 40;

    switch (keyPress.keyCode) {
        case upArrow:
            snake.changeDirection(-1, 0);
            break;
        case leftArrow:
            snake.changeDirection(0, -1);
            break;
        case rightArrow:
            snake.changeDirection(0, 1);
            break;
        case downArrow:
            snake.changeDirection(1, 0);
            break;
    }
}

async function runGame() {
    var running = true;

    while (running) {       
        snake.moveSnake();  
        checkForSnakeDeath(gameOver);
        checkForGoalCapture();
        updateDOM();
        await delay();
    }

    function gameOver() {
        alert("Game over!");
        running = false;
    }
}

function checkForSnakeDeath(gameOver) {
    if (snake.isSnakeDead())
        gameOver();
}

function checkForGoalCapture() {
    const head = snake.getSnakeHead();

    if (goal.isGoal(head[0], head[1])) {
        snake.expandSnake();
        goal.newGoal();
    }
}

function delay() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 60);
    });
}

function updateDOM() {
    for (let row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++) 
        for (let col = 0; col < WIDTH; col++) 
            if (snake.hasSnake(row, col)) 
                colorSnakeInDOM(row, col);
            else if (goal.isGoal(row, col))
                colorGoalInDOM(row, col);
            else
                colorWallInDOM(row, col);
}

function colorSnakeInDOM(row, col) {
    const SNAKE_COLOR = "#00BFFF";

    colorTileInDOM(SNAKE_COLOR, row, col);
}

function colorWallInDOM(row, col) {
    const WALL_COLOR = selectBackgroundColor(row, col);

    colorTileInDOM(WALL_COLOR, row, col);
}

function colorGoalInDOM(row, col) {
    const GOAL_COLOR = "yellow";
        
    colorTileInDOM(GOAL_COLOR, row, col);
}

function colorTileInDOM(color, row, col) {
    const tileDOM = getTileInDOM(row, col);

    tileDOM.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

function getTileInDOM(row, col) {
    const gridDOM = document.querySelector("#grid");
    const rowDOM = gridDOM.rows[row];
    const tileDOM = rowDOM.cells[col];

    return tileDOM;
}

// Dynamically generate HTML for a plain grid
function initialiseGridInDOM() {
    const gridDOM = document.querySelector("#grid");

    for (let row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++) {
        let newRow = createEmptyRowInDOM(row);
        gridDOM.append(newRow);
    }

    updateDOM();
}   

function createEmptyRowInDOM(row) {
    const newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    newRow.className = "row";

    for (let col = 0; col < WIDTH; col++)  {
        let newTile = createEmptyTileInDOM(row, col);
        newRow.append(newTile);
    }

    return newRow;
}

function createEmptyTileInDOM(row, col) {
    const newTile = document.createElement("td");

    newTile.className = "tile";

    return newTile;
}

function selectBackgroundColor(row, col) {
    const BACKGROUND_COLOR1 = "#3dfc03";
    const BACKGROUND_COLOR2 = "#03fc03";

    if ((row + col) % 2 === 0)
        return BACKGROUND_COLOR1;
    else
        return BACKGROUND_COLOR2;
}

function wrapAround([row, col]) {
    if (row === HEIGHT) 
        row = 0;
    if (row < 0)
        row = HEIGHT - 1;    
    if (col === WIDTH)
        col = 0;
    if (col < 0)
        col = WIDTH - 1;

    return [row, col];
}

// Generates a random number whose value lies between lower and upper
function rng(lower, upper) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower;
}

```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, please be indulgent, english is not my native langage :).

Here is my take on your script. I will comment on the modifications I have made.

I have separated your script into chapters (that can lead to separated files if you want) :

- Game logic (snake and goal)
- Game flow (start, loop, game over)
- Controls
- Rendering

I have made some variable alignment and used ES6 shortened method definition (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

---

**GAME LOGIC**

For the snake object I have changed the self executing function to a named function for a better readability.

I have also shortened the method names because we already know we are on the snake object.

For example, I changed snake.expandSnake() to snake.expand().

The reduce onliners were a bit hard to read, so I changed them to multi line.

```
const HEIGHT = 20
const WIDTH  = 20



// GAME LOGIC

function createSnake () {

    const coordinates    = [[0, 0], [1, 0]]
    const moveDirections = [[-1, 0], [-1, 0]]

    function shiftDirections () {
        for (let i = coordinates.length; i > 0; i--) {
            moveDirections[i] = moveDirections[i - 1]
        }
    }

    return {

        hasSnake (row, col) {
            return coordinates.reduce(function (accum, [snakeRow, snakeCol]) {
                return accum || (row === snakeRow && col === snakeCol)
            }, false)
        },

        expand () {
            const head = coordinates[0]
            const headDirection = moveDirections[0]

            coordinates.unshift(
                wrapAround([
                    head[0] + headDirection[0],
                    head[1] + headDirection[1]
                ])
            )

            moveDirections.unshift(headDirection)
        },

        changeDirection (x, y) {
            const isAboutTurn = (
                x === -moveDirections[0][0] ||
                y === -moveDirections[0][1]
            )

            if (!isAboutTurn) {
                moveDirections[0] = [x, y]
            }
        },

        getHead () {
            return coordinates[0]
        },

        isDead () {
            const tail = coordinates.slice(1)
            const head = coordinates[0]

            return tail.reduce(function (accum, [row, col]) {
                return accum || (row === head[0] && col === head[1])
            }, false)
        },

        move () {
            for (let i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
                coordinates[i][0] += moveDirections[i][0]
                coordinates[i][1] += moveDirections[i][1]

                coordinates[i] = wrapAround(coordinates[i])
            }                   

            shiftDirections()
        }

    }

}



function createGoal () {

    let coords = [HEIGHT - 1, WIDTH - 1]

    return {
        newGoal: function () {
            coords = [randomIntBetween(0, HEIGHT), randomIntBetween(0, WIDTH)]
        },

        isGoal: function (row, col) {
            return coords[0] === row && coords[1] === col
        }
    }

}
```

---

**GAME FLOW**

You can see the objects snake and goal are now created in this chapter.

I have renamed checkForSnakeDeath and checkForGoalCapture into handleSnakeDeath and handleGoal, because what you are doing in thoses functions is more than a simple check. In my opinion, a check should just return true or false, or maybe an error object but not doing actions.

```
// GAME FLOW

let snake = createSnake()
let goal  = createGoal()



initialiseGame()

function initialiseGame () {
    initialiseDOMGrid()
    addEventListeners()

    runGame()
}



function addEventListeners () {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', moveSnakeFromInput)
}


async function runGame () {

    var running = true

    while (running) {
        snake.move()
        handleSnakeDeath(gameOver)
        handleGoal()

        paintGrid()

        await delay()
    }

    function gameOver () {
        alert('Game over!')
        running = false
    }

}


function handleSnakeDeath (callback) {
    if (snake.isDead()) {
        callback()
    }
}


function handleGoal () {
    const head = snake.getHead()

    if (goal.isGoal(head[0], head[1])) {
        snake.expand()
        goal.newGoal()
    }
}


function delay () {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 60)
    })
}
```

---

**CONTROLS**

For the controls I have changed the "switch" to key mapping and object methods for better readability and modularity (you can now do moves.left() programmatically if you want).

```
// CONTROLS

const moves = {
    left () {
        snake.changeDirection(-1, 0)
    },
    up () {
        snake.changeDirection(0, -1)
    },
    right () {
        snake.changeDirection(0, 1)
    },
    down () {
        snake.changeDirection(1, 0)
    }
}

const keysMap = {
    37: 'left',
    38: 'up',
    39: 'right',
    40: 'down'
}


function moveSnakeFromInput (keyPress) {
    if (keyPress in keysMap) {
        moves[keysMap[keyPress]]()
    }
}
```

---

**RENDERING**

For the rendering I have put the color variables together for easier changes.
I have split updateDOM (which is now called paintGrid) into two methods : forEachCell and paintCell.

```
// RENDERING


const SNAKE_COLOR  = '#00BFFF'
const GOAL_COLOR   = 'yellow'
const BACKGROUND_1 = '#3dfc03'
const BACKGROUND_2 = '#03fc03'


function paintGrid () {
    forEachCell(paintCell)
}


function forEachCell (iterator) {
    for (let row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++) {
        for (let col = 0; col < WIDTH; col++) {
            iterator(row, col)
        }
    }
}


function paintCell (row, col) {
    if (snake.hasSnake(row, col)) {
        paintSnake(row, col)
    } else if (goal.isGoal(row, col)) {
        paintGoal(row, col)
    } else {
        paintWall(row, col)
    }
}


function paintSnake (row, col) {
    paintTile(SNAKE_COLOR, row, col)
}


function paintWall (row, col) {
    const WALL_COLOR = getBackgroundColor(row, col)

    paintTile(WALL_COLOR, row, col)
}


function paintGoal (row, col) {
    paintTile(GOAL_COLOR, row, col)
}


function paintTile (color, row, col) {
    const tileDOM = getTile(row, col)

    tileDOM.style.backgroundColor = color
}


function getTile (row, col) {
    const gridDOM = document.querySelector('#grid')
    const rowDOM = gridDOM.rows[row]
    const tileDOM = rowDOM.cells[col]

    return tileDOM
}


function initialiseDOMGrid () {
    const gridDOM = document.querySelector('#grid')

    for (let row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++) {
        let newRow = createDOMRow(row)
        gridDOM.append(newRow)
    }

    paintGrid()
}   


function createDOMRow () {
    const newRow = document.createElement('tr')
    newRow.className = 'row'

    for (let col = 0; col < WIDTH; col++)  {
        let newTile = createDOMTile()
        newRow.append(newTile)
    }

    return newRow
}


function createDOMTile () {
    const newTile = document.createElement('td')
    newTile.className = 'tile'

    return newTile
}


function getBackgroundColor (row, col) {
    return (row + col) % 2 === 0 ? BACKGROUND_1 : BACKGROUND_2
}
```

---

**UTILS**

Just some minor readability modifications here

```
// UTILS


function wrapAround ([row, col]) {
    if (row === HEIGHT) {
        row = 0
    }

    if (row < 0) {
        row = HEIGHT - 1
    }

    if (col === WIDTH) {
        col = 0
    }

    if (col < 0) {
        col = WIDTH - 1
    }

    return [row, col]
}


function randomIntBetween (lower, upper) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower
}
```

Obviously this is just my opinion, so just pick what you like in my modifications :-)